# What means slash and tilde in bash before home directory name?

Tags: bash, tilde

What distinguishes between these two lines in the terminal?

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro:/ John$
```

and

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro:~ John$
```

Comment: I don't know macs, but my guess is that the first line says you are in the root directory, and the second line says you are in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

/ is the root of the filesystem.  So your first prompt means you are currently in the root of the filesystem and your name is John:

```
pwd
/
ls
usr var lib bin home etc ...
```

~ is your home directory (typically /home/John).  So the second prompt means you are currently in your home directory and your name is John.

```
pwd
/home/John
ls
Downloads Desktop Documents Pictures ...
```

If there's a user named, say, "tomas" on your system, then ~tomas means his home directory, typically /home/tomas.

Comment: Note that the OP's environment appears to be OS X.  On OS X, the default location for user home directories is `/Users`, not `/home`.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of anything that appears in your shell prompt depends on the value and interpretation of the `$PS1` variable.

Type

```
echo "$PS1"
```

to see the string from which your displayed prompt is derived, and read the Bash manual (assuming your login shell is bash) to see how it's interpreted.

To see the bash manual, type `info bash` or go [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html). The interpretation of `$PS1` is documented in the "Controlling the prompt" section under "Bash features" (section 6.9 in the latest version).

Most likely you have either `\w` or `\W` in your `$PS1`. `\w` expands to

> The current working directory, with `$HOME` abbreviated with a tilde
>   (uses the `$PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable).

and `\W` expands to

> The basename of `$PWD`, with `$HOME` abbreviated with a tilde.

The basename is the last component of the path, so for example `/foo/bar` would be displayed as `/foo/bar` with `\w`, or just as `bar` with `\W`.

In your case, the first prompt:

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro:/ John$
```

probably means you're currently in the root directory, and the second:

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro:~ John$
```

means you're in your home directory.